# publish connected webpages project

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I built a web-based GUI, and I used localhost/its_name to view and develop it. I need to publish it to someone to be able to view it. Is this possible through Github? The GUI contains multiple .php files that call each other when tabs are pressed.
(I used atom io text editor to make this project (not sure if that helps))

Comment: You need a hosting service from the sound of it. There are literally hundreds of options but it is not our remit to make thise sort of suggestions

Comment: Even if I want to share it only with one person in URL form

Comment: Well then you could host it yourself. What OS are you using and what Webserver are you running

Comment: I am using windows 10

Comment: Webserver? Are you using XAMPP or WAMPServer or IIS

Comment: @RiggsFolly I used XAMPP

Comment: So setup a Virtual Host, making sure that it can only be connected to from a specific IP address, your other persons ip address. Then its cheap and secure. You will have to setup port forwarding on your router, but all this is available to find out ont'internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your project to be viewed by others but don't want to spend money or pay for a domain name, etc. Then you can use Heroku for it. It is a very good hosting service for projects and it can be very helpful if you don't have time and you want your project to be up right now.

Even I have one of my projects hosted right now on Heroku: [spend-elons-money](https://spend-elons-money.herokuapp.com/)

With the Heroku CLI, you can easily host your project from your terminal or command prompt!
I hope this is something you were looking for. If not, please let me know!